Images in table alignment
I want to align those images in the center of each cell horizontally and vertically
any ideas why my code doesnt work?

\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec={Q[valign=m, halign=c] Q[valign=m, halign=c] Q[valign=m, halign=c] Q[valign=m, halign=c]},
  row{1}={halign=c},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
sda & Front & Back & Side \\
AAAA   & 
\raisebox{0pt}{\adjustbox{width=4cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}}} & 
\raisebox{0pt}{\adjustbox{width=4cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}}} & 
\raisebox{0pt}{\adjustbox{width=5cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}} \\
\end{longtblr}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can use the valign=c option from adjustbox to centre your images vertically:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
  cells={halign=c},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
sda & Front & Back & Side \\
AAAA   & 
\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=c]{example-grid-100x100pt} & 
\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=c]{example-grid-100x100pt} & 
\includegraphics[width=5cm,valign=c]{example-image-duck} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


